# What is the simplest way to parse logical expressions from a string in java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, expression

I have a number of strings in a query-like format (using column names, 'and', 'or', parentheses, and the relational operators) that I need to parse in the form:

"column1 > 100"

"column1 = 120 and column3 = 200"

"((column2 = 100) or (column3 = 50 and column1 = 20))"

What would be the best way that I could parse and store each expression for use? I think parsing the string using a bunch of string.substring() and string.indexOf would be good, but I'm unsure how I could store each expression in a useful way to pop() them.

Comment: the simplest way would be to use an already existing api.

Comment: The simplest way or the best way?  The best way is likely a parse tool like ANTLR, but if you don't want the hassle of learning a new tool, and your expressions are *very* simple, you can probably just stick with Java Standard APIs.

Comment: Depends on how you want them to be parsed. Easiest way is using some existing library, and then comes some sort of regex pattern I guess.